# Probability that the ratio of products of randomly chosen natural numbers is unbounded

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability

Let $N$ be a finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$, where $|N|>1$. For $i\in\mathbb{N}$, let $a_i$ and $b_i$ be chosen uniformly at random from $N$. Is it true that $\mathbb{P}[\sup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{\frac{a_1\cdots a_n}{b_1\cdots b_n}\}=\infty]=1$? Note that given the symmetry involved, I believe this should be the same as asking if $\mathbb{P}[\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\{\frac{a_1\cdots a_n}{b_1\cdots b_n}\}=0]=1$.

This question came up while looking at the coarse geometry of trees, and if it is true then it has a nice corollary in that area. Unfortunately I do not have the background in probability to tell if this is an easy question or not, let alone answer it. I suspect it is true based only on the intuition of the people I have already asked, and doing some tests in python.

Comment: @IosifPinelis Apologies, I'm new to posting here and forgpt about the "accept answer" button! Thank you for the reminder (and the great answer).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is true. Indeed, let
$$S_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i=\frac1s\,\ln\frac{a_1\cdots a_n}{b_1\cdots b_n},$$
where $Y_i:=X_i/s$, $X_i:=\ln\frac{a_i}{b_i}=\ln a_i-\ln b_i$, and $s:=\sqrt{Var\, X_i}\in(0,\infty)$. Note that the $Y_i$'s are i.i.d. zero-mean unit-variance random variables. So,
$$P\Big(\sup_{n\ge1}\frac{a_1\cdots a_n}{b_1\cdots b_n}=\infty\Big)
=P(\sup_{n\ge1}S_n=\infty)\ge P\Big(\limsup_n \frac{S_n}{\sqrt{2n\ln\ln n}}>0\Big)=1,$$
by the [law of the iterated logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm).
So,
$$P\Big(\sup_{n\ge1}\frac{a_1\cdots a_n}{b_1\cdots b_n}=\infty\Big)=1.$$

---

Similarly,
$$P\Big(\inf_{n\ge1}\frac{a_1\cdots a_n}{b_1\cdots b_n}=0\Big)=1;$$
alternatively, write
$$P\Big(\inf_{n\ge1}\frac{a_1\cdots a_n}{b_1\cdots b_n}=0\Big)=
P\Big(\sup_{n\ge1}\frac{b_1\cdots b_n}{a_1\cdots a_n}=\infty\Big)=1.$$

---

Also, in view of Strassen's [converse to the law of the iterated logarithm](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF00539114) (and [Kolmogorov's zero–one law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero%E2%80%93one_law)), we do not need to assume that the $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s are chosen uniformly from a finite subset of $\mathbb N$ -- they can be sampled, independently, from any non-degenerate distribution whatsoever on $(0,\infty)$. Another proof of Strassen's result was given by [Heyde](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-applied-probability/article/abs/on-the-converse-to-the-iterated-logarithm-law/B475B8821B2A214C43A6BA16FFC4E086).

Comment: Does your final generalisation cover the case where $E[X_i^2]$ is infinite and perhaps $E[X_i]$ undefined (despite $X_i$ being symmetrically distributed about $0$)? Presumably it does - the probability of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i$ exceeding any given bound for some $n$ will be $1$.

Comment: @Henry : Yes. As I said, the $a_i$'s and $b_i$'s can be sampled, independently, from any non-degenerate distribution whatsoever on $(0,\infty)$. Whatever $X_i$'s one can this way will be just fine.